# Usefulness of Matched $z$ transform Method

Tags: discrete-signals, sampling, continuous-signals, z-transform, conversion

I'm aware that the matched $z$ transform method maps between the continuous $s$ plane and the discrete/digital $z$ plane but my question is - when would this be necessary? Why would we need to convert between the two?
Thanks

Comment: Did you find the answers to your previous questions helpful? If so, please accept and/or upvote them, or leave a comment explaining why they were not helpful, so they can be improved. Otherwise people might get discouraged answering any of your newer questions.

Comment: Apologies, I hadn't realised this was the case!

Comment: it appears that Janitt check-marked the answers as succeeding to answer the question.  must she also upvote them, @MattL. ?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: Of course not, but the answers hadn't been accepted till a few minutes ago :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the Matched Z method is the simplest method to convert an analog filter design with transfer function $H_\mathrm{a}(s)$ to a digital filter design $H(z)$.  It does it by mapping every pole and every zero from the $s$-plane to the $z$-plane using:

$$ z \leftarrow e^{sT} $$

where $T \triangleq \frac{1}{f_\mathrm{s}}$ is the sampling period and the reciprocal of the sample rate, $f_\mathrm{s}$.  Stable analog filters get mapped to stable digital filters.  That's all that it is.

The other two common methods are the Bilinear Transform, which approximates the above mapping:

$$ z \leftarrow \frac{1+\frac{sT}{2}}{1-\frac{sT}{2}} \approx \frac{e^{\frac{sT}{2}}}{e^{\frac{-sT}{2}}} = e^{sT} $$

and the Impulse Invariant method which is a time-domain way of looking at things:

$$ h[n] \leftarrow h_\mathrm{a}(nT) $$

Comment: i'll return to this later and put in some definitions.